# Production error: "image is not present in the asset pipeline" although it is there and working in dev environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm new to devops and can't figure out what's going on. Today we pushed a branch to production where we are using new images for a view.

Everything worked fine in development environment, but when it was promoted to production we started getting errors related to the new images not being found in the asset pipeline

```
  <div class="text-center my-10">
    <%= link_to t("url.static_site") do %>
      <%= image_tag "logo-white-no-background" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

error:

```
The asset "logo-white-no-background" is not present in the asset pipeline.
```

I've tried running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` locally to emulate what happens in production (as I understand everything under /assets is precompiled and served by the web server) and I don't get any errors.

The only thing that I find different in the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/asset_pipeline.html) is that I'm not passing the file extension in the `image_tag`, although like I said it is working find in development (and actually breaks if I add the extension in that environment).

Should I try forcing a pre-compile on production to see if it is loaded correctly?

What else can I try?

Comment: `and actually breaks if I add the extension in that environment` - adding the extension should not break anything. Add the extension and make it work in dev and it will work in production too.

Comment: What error you receive if you add the extension in dev?

Comment: Sorry, I must've done something wrong because it is now working in development with the file extension.

Why should this fix it? What's wrong with not providing the extension to image_tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add the extension to make it work in production!

It shouldn't break it in development, make sure you run `rails assets:clean` and `rails assets:clobber` to clean out the compiled assets and that you have the right file extension!

Comment: Thanks. I've found it's actually a Rails bug and it's already been reported => https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/35651#issuecomment-694185487

Answer (score 1):

The extension is a hint to not only browsers or but also some backend servers. Nobody forces developers to add the extension; however, you can see adding the extension as a good coding habit.

For example, your image is jpg, but the browser shows it as png. You found the image shown correctly maybe it's just happened to that browser guessed the file type correctly. In some scenarios like downloading the file from S3, if there is no extension provided, it will be served as a *pdf* file.

Btw, about your problem, because it didn't show the image in the production environment. You can first check the src from  by inspecting the source code. If the browser cannot find the image file via that URL, the URL is just invalid. After inspecting the image's URL, you can try to generate the right URL then.